# Workflow Designer encountered problems with your document

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, workflow

I found out that the problem is this part :   **this:_a650.argument1="this is a test"**    Does anyone know what does this expression in XAML file mean within Activity tag?

If I take this out     **this:_a650.argument1="this is a test"**
then I can open the workflow file in a workflow designer with no problem, but when it is there I get the follwoing error message: Workflow Designer encountered problems with your document 
Please check the document for invalid content,namespace, references or reference loops.
could not find member argument1 in type _a650
   Any ideas?

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sap sads" x:Class="{x:Null}" this:_a650.argument1="this is a test"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities"
 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
 xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities"
 xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
 xmlns:s1="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System"
 xmlns:s2="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Core"
 xmlns:s3="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.ServiceModel"
 xmlns:sads="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2010/xaml/activities/debugger"
 xmlns:sap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation"
 xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"
 xmlns:this="clr-namespace:"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <x:Members>
    <x:Property Name="argument1" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
  </x:Members>
  <sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize>526.4,369.6</sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize>
  <mva:VisualBasic.Settings>Assembly references and imported namespaces for internal implementation</mva:VisualBasic.Settings>
  <Sequence sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="486.4,329.6">
    <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
        <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
      </scg:Dictionary>
    </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    <If Condition="[2 = 2]" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="464,204.8" />
  </Sequence>
</Activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `x:Class={x:Null}` attribute to `_a650`. XAML should open fine then.

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sap" x:Class="_a650" this:_a650.argument1="this is a test" ... >
```

The expression  **this:_a650.argument1="this is a test"** together with the  *Property* definition inside *Members* declare an IN argument of type *String* (with "this is a test" as its *default* value) belonging to a `_a650` type.

```
<x:Property Name="argument1" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
```

The answer to this question is related to one of your other questions [Visual Studio 2010 - Workflow Designer encountered problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835934/how-to-recover-from-workflow-designer-encountered-problems-with-your-document) on SO. Since, the arguments have to be declared as members of a type but the "root" activity has not been named to derive the type from; a random type name (like _a650) is generated and used.

The "root" activity name, however, is not updated and so upon XAML serialization `x:Class` is still generated as `{x:Null}`. This results in a namespace error when this same XAML is opened in Workflow Designer as the XAML parser is unable to find any `x:Class` declared to be of `_a650` type.