# Why my rehosted WF4.0 designer does not display the xaml file name on the Designer Surface

Tags: xaml, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

As you can see on the left top corner of the middle pane instead of a workflow xaml file name you see the following _48d3  which I believe is the default class name.  What have I done wrong because I should see something like Workflow1.XAML

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your re-hosted Workflow Designer as

```
_rootActivity = new Sequence {
    Activities = {
        new WriteLine { ... }
    }
};
_workflowDesigner.Load(new ActivityBuilder { Implementation = _rootActivity,
                                             Name = "WorkflowConsoleApplication1.Workflow1" });
```

This would generate the name `WorkflowConsoleApplication1.Workflow1` similar to the default workflow name given to your XAML by Visual Studio 2010.

References:
My answer to [Visual Studio 2010 - Workflow Designer encountered problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835934/how-to-recover-from-workflow-designer-encountered-problems-with-your-document)